# mb_check_encoding for Windows encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I get an input string and try to check if it's a valid windows-1255 string:

```
mb_check_encoding($string, 'windows-1255');
```

I get an error message: "Invalid encoding "windows-1255""

The encoding name 'windows-1255' is probably correct, as I use it in the "iconv" function and it works fine. I also tried "WINDOWS-1255" and "Windows-1255" and got the same results.

How can I check if the string is valid windows-1255 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, trying to sniff the encoding is *always* broken one way or the other.

The following isn't tested, but *should* work if the encoding is registered with your system. Make sure you test it thoroughly (negatives as well as positives) before using.

You could use `iconv()` convert it from Windows-1255 to UTF-8 and back. If it's still the same string, it's valid Windows-1255.

```
$string = "צקר"; // the source file needs to be Windows-1255 as well 
$string_1255 = iconv ("Windows-1255", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $string);
$string_final = iconv ("UTF-8", "Windows-1255//IGNORE", $string_1255);

if ($string == $string_final)  
    echo "Yay!!! :)"; 
   else 
    echo "No :(";
```